# place an image above revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I am trying to place an image partially above revolution slider (a part of the upper side of slider should be covered by the image)
I tried with

```
image{position:relative;
z-index:10;
}
slider{position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

but it does not seem to work
here is the link of the page: http://qebaalrabee.com/green-main/
here is how it should be: [image]

Comment: Try `position:absolute`. The relative positioning is pushing everything down. Add `left:0;right:0;margin:auto;` to center the image.

Comment: your solution did not work at all
I found a stupid solution which is placing the image under the slider and using margin-top:-20vw; 
it worked! could not find explanation

Comment: It may have been margin:0 ...  But it was from the top of the head. Whatever works ..  ;-)

Comment: seems like downside elements have higher z-index
yeah sure, whatever works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might seem illogical but the solution I found is placing the image under the slider and using `margin-top:-20vw;`

it worked!
seems like downside elements have higher z-index