# Visual Composer - Make the Row Flow on another row?

Tags: wordpress

Visual Composer - Make the Row Flow on another row?

Can anyone help me to achieve this row like the image in visual composer - wordpress?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofeFn.png)

I want to make the brown row overflow. I try to "margin-top: -50" but the background was hidden in the above row?

Comment: Do not work on the row itself, let the element inside the row flow, it will work with margin-top

Comment: The row is always hidden by the above row when i set "margin-top:-50px". How can i make the row infont of the above row like a layer?

Comment: I faced such issue before, try the opposite, make this row above of the row that is hiding it and use margin-bottom:-value

Comment: it is not logical I know but it might work
check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022904/place-an-image-above-revolution-slider

Comment: Can you log in into my dashboard and fix its for me?

Comment: sure, but you will have to wait for a few hours, can not do that now

Comment: Hey, can you log in now and fix its for me? usr: diamondbay, pass: thuy@1234